# Stack Overflow - Official WMD editor

Tags: support, stack-overflow, editor

Which of the numerous WMD editors are used on Stack Overflow?

When I Google SO and WMD Editor there are several results linking to several different forks. What I've found so far are:

- https://github.com/derobins/wmd: Appears to not have been updated in 3 years, so guessing no.
- http://code.google.com/p/wmd/: Same as #1
- http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/: Was recently updated a few days ago
- https://github.com/ChiperSoft/wmd/: Hasn't been updated for a few months
- https://github.com/bumpux/mmwords: Updated recently, but nothing related to WMD

Side note, most of the questions related to this topic, on MSO, date back to 2008-2010.

Some clarification would be great.

Comment: @TimStone: Ahhh my bad, didn't see that when I was digging around. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I can't claim to be an authority on this subject, but the [editor](/questions/tagged/editor) [tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/editor/info) has the following to say.

> This editor is open source.
>
> On the server it is MarkdownSharp:
>   https://github.com/balpha/markdownsharp
>
> On the client it is PageDown:
>   https://github.com/StackExchange/pagedown

Comment: Thanks Chris, I was thinking PageDown as well due to the recent update activity, but would like to be sure. I'm going to hold off on accepting to see if I can get an "official" word.

Comment: @DigitalPrecision Sounds good. For what it's worth, it also looks like [Jeff added this information in September 2011](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/102057/3).

Comment: @DigitalPrecision Not that my word is necessarily any more official than Chris', but PageDown is indeed the official project that's being maintained and used on the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Ahhh that's good enough for me then. Thanks for the help guys. Pagedown it is.

Comment: What is MarkdownSharp used for? Pagedown includes the validation and everything you need, no?

Comment: It seems the [stack exchange github page](http://stackexchange.github.io/) has changed and pagedown is now on github here: [balpha/pagedown](https://github.com/balpha/pagedown)

Comment: Both `http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/` and `http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/` are broken now (404) (Google Code shutdown 2016-01-15). Perhaps update?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Nice catch! Just updated it now.