# What richtext editor is Stack Overflow using?

Tags: discussion, editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which tools and technologies build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

As the title states, What richtext editor is Stack Overflow using?

Comment: I wasn't aware of that site.  I second the vote.

Comment: Being a duplicate there, it is probably best to delete this question.

Comment: It's *not* a rich text editor. It's plain old text.

Answer (score 1):

Unofficially, it is pagedown (see [Stackoverflow - Official WMD Editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121981/stackoverflow-official-wmd-editor)).