# Why does Stack Overflow use a separate WMD renderer server vs. client side?

Tags: discussion, editor

According to the answer to this question, two programs are used:

[Stackoverflow - Official WMD Editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121981/stackoverflow-official-wmd-editor/121982#121982?newreg=95460de18b794ffabf7175a7b0bc6884)

> On the server it is MarkdownSharp:
>   https://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/
>
> On the client it is PageDown: https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/

Why not just one?

Comment: One major difference is that in the browser you'll need to run JavaScript (technically they could run an Applet or an ActiveX but let's not go there) while their serverside stuff is all .Net/C# based. To even consider using the same implementation you need to have a common layer to base such implementation on. As you're more or less bound/condemned to JS client side, they should have changed to/implement a NodeJS backend, assuming the client and server requirements for the feature are the same.

Comment: The current repo are on GitHub: https://github.com/StackExchange/pagedown and https://github.com/balpha/markdownsharp